# Rails not generating model correctly (no column names recognised) (Hartl tutorial, Chapter 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

Upon entering

```
rails generate model Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

into Terminal, I get the following response:

```
invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140306034740_create_microposts.rb
  create    app/models/micropost.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/micropost_spec.rb
```

When I check the micropost.rb file in models, I find this:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

It is neither inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration, nor recognising content:string or user_id:integer as in the tutorial. I feel like I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have post is model. model inherited from ActiveRecord::Base, go to the db and migrate folder to get the migration file for the same that is inherited from ActiveRecord::Migration.

Comment: Yup, just saw that, was about to delete this question from embarrassment but I think I'll leave it up in case anyone else makes the same mistake...

Comment: Says I have to wait one minute :)